# C# syntax variable data type in postion with class type

Tags: c#

I am a bit confuse of how does a class in the postion of a (variable data type/data variable type) like (int, char, etc) be used.

example;

Normal Syntax would be like:

```
  // <access specifier> <data type variable> name;

 public int Numbers ()
        {           
        }
```

But this i dont understand.

```
// <access specifier> <data type class> name;

    public Animal Tiger()
{    
}
```

or

```
 // <     > <data type class> name;

  IEnumerable Animal Dog()
  {       
  }
```

What is the Use of using a class as a replacment of a variable data type?

Comment: What do you mean by "replacement of a variable data type" and "normal syntax"? These are functions which return objects of different types. `Numbers` returns an int, `Tiger` returns an `Animal`, `Dog` is uncompilable. P.S. There are no terms like "data type variable" and "data type class", use commonly used terms to describe your problem if you want others to understand it.

Comment: Method 2: The method `Tiger` returns a type `Animal` instance. Method 3: should not compile as `IEnumerable` is not an access specifier.

Comment: `int` is not a variable data type, its `int`.

Comment: In second method name of the method is `Tiger` and the return type is `Animal` just like the other methods.

Comment: "IEnumerable Animal Dog"? You sure you're not looking at IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator?

Comment: I am tryin to learn Interface and what is uses are.
what i know in is that class is a higher Level than method. (if i am correct)
so im a bit confuse how can i make a method with a class  (normaly in a Basic syntax i can use int,char,string,void etc)

so if i can use a class in a method Syntax than is the (int,string,char) are also classes?

Comment: Numbers is of type INT, for it to make sense you might want a list of numbers: List<Int> Numbers() as Int Numbers() will refer to a single integer value not more than one.

Comment: @k9nneo1191 yes and no. The point is they are all "types". Some are reference types and some are value types (plenty of docs around to explain the difference). So when you see `public String Foo()` the `String` part is a type and any type can go in it's place. However, interfaces are different. I would suggest that brush-up on your types before you delve into interfaces.

Comment: if not already, have a read of this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Int, string, byte, etc are built-in data types of C#.

A created class like Animal, Dog, Car with fields and methods, can be called as user defined data type. Examples:

This creates a variable named x of int type

```
public int x;
```

This call a method with return type int

```
public int Sum()
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Now imagine you created a class called Animal:

```
public class Animal
{
   public string name;
}
```

This create a instance of an object called tiger of type Animal:

```
Animal tiger = new Animal();
```

And this call a method with Animal return type:

```
public Animal GetAnimal()
{
    //method logic goes here...
}
```

Comment: thx Fabri Damazio.
1 question what happens if the Animal class has method and field.
and then i call it like the last part of your example. 

is that disame like inheritance?